# Some data on this page is currently being calculated, and the page will be refreshed automatically

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pootle

I just installed pootle and I'm having this messagge "Some data on this page is currently being calculated, and the page will be refreshed automatically x seconds". Upon going to the admin page, I found out that there is a failed job so I run on my command line pootle retry_failed_jobs.

And this is what it says :/

```
`DoesNotExist: Directory matching query does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 568, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 495, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 683, in update_cache_job
    instance._update_cache_job(keys, decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 534, in _update_cache_job
    create_update_cache_job_wrapper(p, keys_for_parent, decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 693, in create_update_cache_job_wrapper
    connection.on_commit(_create_update_cache_job)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction_hooks/mixin.py", line 31, in on_commit
    func()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 692, in _create_update_cache_job
    create_update_cache_job(queue, instance, keys, decrement=decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 707, in create_update_cache_job
    last_job_key = instance.get_last_job_key()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 299, in get_last_job_key
    key = self.get_cachekey()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/apps/pootle_translationproject/models.py", line 373, in get_cachekey
    return self.directory.pootle_path
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 572, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Directory matching query does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 568, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 495, in perform
    self._result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 683, in update_cache_job
    instance._update_cache_job(keys, decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 534, in _update_cache_job
    create_update_cache_job_wrapper(p, keys_for_parent, decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 693, in create_update_cache_job_wrapper
    connection.on_commit(_create_update_cache_job)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/transaction_hooks/mixin.py", line 31, in on_commit
    func()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 692, in _create_update_cache_job
    create_update_cache_job(queue, instance, keys, decrement=decrement)
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 707, in create_update_cache_job
    last_job_key = instance.get_last_job_key()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/core/mixins/treeitem.py", line 299, in get_last_job_key
    key = self.get_cachekey()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/apps/pootle_translationproject/models.py", line 373, in get_cachekey
    return self.directory.pootle_path
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 572, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get()
  File "/var/www/pootle/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 357, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Directory matching query does not exist.
`
```

Comment: nothing can be more accurate: `DoesNotExist: Directory matching query does not exist.`

Comment: but what does that mean? and how do i fix it?

Comment: it means, Directory object doesnot exist in your database

Comment: Did you initialize your database using the `initdb` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually happened when I deleted the language of the project using the admin panel, then suddenly somewhat deleted the folder of that language in the system. What I did is to create a new project and copy the translation files. So I didn't resolve the problem but I was able to remove the refreshing of data.

Answer (score 0):

The stats in Pootle are managed by Redis.  Pootle can sometimes get into a state where the stats are broken.  Issues like broken files can cause this.  You can clean up the stats [using this guide](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/server/rq.html).

I'd also [report the situation](https://github.com/translate/pootle/issues/new) and any tracebacks to the Pootle developers so that they can make the stats calculations more robust.